Using multiprocessing to simulate multiple computers
I want to use multiprocessing (Python) to simulate the following scenario: there are multiple computing centers, each with multiple computers, and these computers can execute tasks in parallel. Consider each process as representing a computer. Is this approach feasible?
I initially used threading to simulate the scenario, but it felt unreasonable.

"I initially used threading to simulate the scenario, but it felt unreasonable." What made you think that, and what alternative method do you think there is?

Performance-wise, multiprocessing is going to be better than multithreading in python because of the GIL. The 3.13 version is getting around that, but it is still experimental.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
